# How to implement next-with-apollo with react-apollo SSR?

Tags: javascript, apollo, react-apollo, next.js, apollo-client

I am using `react-apollo` with `Next.js` the way it is illustrated in the [example from the Next.js repo](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo).

I want to integrate it with the [`next-with-apollo`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-with-apollo) package that provides us not only the `initialState`, but also the `headers`.

The example in Next.js repo's `init-apollo.js` looks like this

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink } from 'apollo-boost'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

let apolloClient = null

// Polyfill fetch() on the server (used by apollo-client)
if (!process.browser) {
  global.fetch = fetch
}

function create (initialState) {
  // Check out https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/4611 if you want to use the AWSAppSyncClient
  return new ApolloClient({
    connectToDevTools: process.browser,
    ssrMode: !process.browser, // Disables forceFetch on the server (so queries are only run once)
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: `${process.env.ENDPOINT}/graphql`, // Server URL (must be absolute)
      credentials: 'same-origin', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`,
      request: operation => {
        operation.setContext({
          fetchOptions: {
            credentials: 'include',
          }
        })
      }
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {})
  })
}

export default function initApollo (initialState) {
  // Make sure to create a new client for every server-side request so that data
  // isn't shared between connections (which would be bad)
  if (!process.browser) {
    return create(initialState)
  }

  // Reuse client on the client-side
  if (!apolloClient) {
    apolloClient = create(initialState)
  }

  return apolloClient
}
```

I want to implement the `headers` argument from `next-with-apollo` package like this

```js
import withApollo from 'next-with-apollo'
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'

function createClient({ headers }) {

  return new ApolloClient({
    uri: `${process.env.ENDPOINT}/graphql`,
    request: operation => {
      operation.setContext({
        fetchOptions: {
          credentials: 'include',
        },
        headers
      })
    }
  })

}

export default withApollo(createClient)
```

The `headers` argument will allow me to fetch the data from cookies.

I tried to do this but got errors: `init-apollo.js`

```js
function create (initialState, headers) {
  // Check out https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/4611 if you want to use the AWSAppSyncClient
  return new ApolloClient({
    connectToDevTools: process.browser,
    ssrMode: !process.browser, // Disables forceFetch on the server (so queries are only run once)
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: `${process.env.ENDPOINT}/graphql`, // Server URL (must be absolute)
      credentials: 'same-origin', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`,
      request: operation => {
        operation.setContext({
          fetchOptions: {
            credentials: 'include',
          },
          headers
        })
      }
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {})
  })
}
export default withApollo(({ ctx, headers, initialState }) => {

  if (!process.browser) {
    return create(initialState, headers)
  }

  // Reuse client on the client-side
  if (!apolloClient) {
    apolloClient = create(initialState, headers)
  }

  return apolloClient

})
```

Doing so, gave me weird errors.
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined` from `with-apollo-client.js` of the [Next.js repo example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-apollo/lib/with-apollo-client.js).

**I want the access to `headers` somehow in the `create()` function. How do I get the access? Is there some other way?**